# Show posts from all categories

Tags: categories, theme-development, customization, themes, templates

I have a site with 5 different categories, each of them with a `notices` section.
I would like also to have another section to see the latest notices from any category.

So far, I figured out that I can just use this in the URL `?cat=20,25,30,35` and it will return exactly what I want (if I'm not mistaken).

Now, I would like to know how could I create another template page for that particular section containing all the notices.

Usually I do something like this in my `category.php`:

```
if($this_category->slug == "groups-london" || $this_category->slug == "groups-cambridge"){
    include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/groups.php');
}else{
    include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/general.php');
}
```

BUt in this case I can not use the same approach because I noticed the `$this_category` only contains the information from the category passed as the first parameter in the URL.
So, in this case `?cat=20,25,30,35` only from category with ID `20`.

Any recommendation? 
Maybe I should just use a completely different approach to solve this issue?

Comment: What is `$this_category`? How is that set?

Comment: This `$this_category = get_category($cat);`

Answer (score 0):

You need [`get_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) with an `include` argument:

```
if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {
  $this_category = get_categories(
    array(
      'include' => $_GET['cat']
    )
  );
  var_dump($this_category);
}
```

You will get an `array` of `stdClass` objects containing category data. There are several ways to parse that but this might do:

```
if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {
  $this_category = get_categories(
    array(
      'include' => $_GET['cat']
    )
  );
  //   var_dump($this_category);
  $cats = wp_list_pluck($this_category,'slug');
  var_dump($cats);
  $needle = array('groups-london','groups-cambridge');
  var_dump(array_intersect($needle,$cats));
  if(array_intersect($needle,$cats)){
    include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/groups.php');
  }else{
    include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/general.php');
  }
}
```